# Retrieve those records whose IsActive Column is True. Entity Framework and LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

&& z.DisplayDurations.Count > 0Here is the scenario. There are 2 entity classes:

```
class DisplayDuration
{
    public int DisplayDurationID { get; set; }
    public double Seconds { get; set; }
    public string SecondsString { get; set; }
    public int? FK_Zone { get; set; }
    public double? BasePrice { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}

class Zone
{
    public int ZoneID { get; set; }
    public int FK_ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual List<DisplayDuration> DisplayDurations { get; set; } //Contains the list of DisplayDuration
}
```

Now when i try to get list of zone on the basis of DisplayCount then all DisplayDuration Regarding that zoneid all DisplayDuration comes up while i want only DisplayDuration with IsActive value "True". Is there any way to achieve it.
I am doing like that.

```
    public List<Zone> RetrieveActiveZonesHavingDDurations()
    {
        var zone = from z in _context.Zones
                   where z.Active &&  && z.DisplayDurations.Count > 0
                   select z;
        return zone.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: i want only DisplayDuration with IsActive value "True" --> in your code IsActive is on Zone not in DisplayDuration

Comment: @Gregoire can you please give me another solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is not possible to filter on an association property (i.e. only get active DisplayDurations) and also it's not possible to construct entities in Linq-to-entities, you need either an anonymous object or an intermediate class to mimic Zone.

```
public class ZoneModel
{
    public int ZoneID { get; set; }
    public int FK_ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<DisplayDuration> DisplayDurations { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var zones = _context.Zones
    .Where(z => z.Active && z.DisplayDuration.Count>0)
    .Select(z => new ZoneModel
    {
        ZoneID = z.ZoneID,
        FK_ProductID = z.FK_ProductID,
        Name = z.Name,
        Width = z.Width,
        Height = z.Height,
        Active = z.Active,
        Description = z.Description,
        DisplayDurations = z.DisplayDurations
            .Where(d => d.IsActive.HasValue && d.IsActive.Value==true)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update your method like below.**

```
public List<Zone> RetrieveActiveZonesHavingDDurations()
{
    var zone = from z in _context.Zones
                   where z.Active
                   && z.DisplayDurations != null
                   && z.DisplayDurations.Count > 0
                   && z.DisplayDurations.Any<DisplayDurations>(x => x.IsActive == true)
               select z;

    return zone.ToList();

}
```

Comment: This error comes up when trying the given solution.
Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.